# FFMPEG output the wrong color when using it with BackColour / OutlineColour

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

I have tried both OutlineColour, BackColour and BoxColour none of this worked well with colors, only black/white in both opaque and with transparency works. I am not sure how to fix this code, It's been 3 days searching for a solution

my color is E63946 clearly it's red

[image: color tag]

When making the necessary adjustments with the code below

```
  const bgColorHex = '#E63946';
  const bgColorFFmpeg = bgColorHex.replace('#', '&H00');
  console.log(bgColorFFmpeg);
```

I use with the code below

```
 const ffmpeg = spawn("ffmpeg", [
    "-i",
    "test.mp4",
    "-vf",
    `subtitles=${subtitlePath}:force_style='BorderStyle=3,Shadow=no,BackColour=${bgColorFFmpeg},OutlineColour=${bgColorFFmpeg}'`,
    "-c:a",
    "copy",
    "-progress", "pipe:1",
    outputPath,
  ]);
```

This is the result I get

[image: code output]

I tried other methods like with tinycolor, same issue

```
const bgColor = `&H${tinycolor(bgColorHex).toHex8().substr(2)}`;
```

Please help this is very confusing it should be easy to input a color into ffmpeg, text color on the other hand gave me no issue at all only this captions background is causing problems.

Let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

If anybody looking for a solution I found it, ffmpeg except a specific order for rgb, install tinycolor and here's the code:

```
const bgColorHex = '#E63946';
const bgColorRGB = tinycolor(bgColorHex).toRgb();
const bgColorFFmpeg = `&H00${toHex(bgColorRGB.b)}${toHex(bgColorRGB.g)}${toHex(bgColorRGB.r)}`;

function toHex(value) {
  const hex = value.toString(16);
  return hex.length === 1 ? `0${hex}` : hex;
}
```